# ¿Cómo salir de una rama al master en Git?

Tags: git

[image: Ayuda]
¿Cómo salgo de la rama en la que estoy actualmente a la rama master?
Estoy iniciando en este mundo y bueno no se que debo hacer.

Comment: Bienvenido, considera leer [ask], a donde deseas cambiarte? especifica por favor, saludos!

Comment: Jorgesys, la cosa es que si te puedes fijar en la rama en la que estoy que tiene numeros y letras, de ahi no se como salir a la rama master

Comment: @BetaM gracias bro

Comment: Ya sali a la rama master, gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Me senti hacker xdxd

Answer (score 1):

Si te fijas, al final de la sentencia de la consola tienes un SHA hexadecimal de 8 caracteres que es una abreviación del SHA que identifica a un commit. Por lo que estás parado sobre un commit en particular, que no es más que un branch en un momento de tiempo.

Para volver a master:
`git checkout master`

Leyendo los comentarios veo que solucionaste tu inquietud, de todos modos te aliento a que compartas lo que aprendiste o des por resuelto tu problema clasificando una respuesta para quien tenga tu duda y llegue a esta pregunta pueda encontrar respuesta.

Comment: ... o con el _nuevo_ `git switch master`.